# Accessing a member function through an object

Tags: c++, function, object, member

so I have two classes, let's say `class A` and `class B`. In class B's constructor I create an object of type A(private). In class A I have a member function that displays the content of A, `void displayA()`.

Now i run `int main()`, I create an object of type B(ideally also object of type A stored in B). My question is how do i use the method in A through B?

I tried `objB.displayA()`, but that obviously didn't work. Do I need to create a member function in B that calls member function in A? Or is there a more elegant solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class B` must have a member variable of type `class A`. For example:

```
class B
{
public:
    A a;
    int x;
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
B objB;
objB.a.displayA();
```

Comment: didn't know about that, thanks :) But what if the `object a` is private? do i need a getter?

Comment: Yes. Instead of a pure `getter` (they're often not a great idea) consider having B have a function that calls `a.displayA`.  If you put in getters etc. for every function of `a` then you may as well make `a` public.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to pass `objB` the instance of `class A` that you are changing, and then inside the function that you pass it, call `obA.displayA();`, or you could create `objA` as a class variable of `objB`, and then call `objA.displayA();` in any of the functions of B.

Answer (score 1):

first, do you no public and private?
and ,you in your class B,is it have variable which type is class A;
like this

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    public:
        void displayA() {
            std::cout << "call a" << std::endl;
        }   
};

class B
{
    public:
        B():a(){}
        A a;
};
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    B b;
    b.a.displayA();
    return 0;
}
```

and than thd class B also can be:

```
`class B
 {
  public:
      B():a(){}
      A a;
      void call() {
          this -> a.displayA();
      }
  };`
```

and than call the call() which in class B

Comment: they are private, sorry

Comment: you means the variable of a is private?and the code above the secend class B can call the displayA(),0.0

Comment: object a is private. Only constructors and member functions are public. Should i then add a getter for object a?

Comment: yes ,it can get the private var a,you had better to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance),and [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/access-rules.html)it can be resolve you problem,:)